# Caching Images while using Parse

Tags: parsing, swift

I'm creating a social media app.
I want to know a way to cache a users profile picture once downloaded from the Parse network and then each time the app is loaded check if an updated picture has been found and load that one, then cache that one.

I have no idea how to approach this, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of third-party libraries for caching you can find on Github, or you can simply use `NSUserDefaults` or `CoreData` to save the pictures(or really anything) to disk. To check if a picture was modified, you can give the picture an identifier, compare it with the response from the server, and re-save the picture, or do whatever is needed.